# how to write a function using list comprehension in haskell?

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension, pointfree

I've written this function using `map`, but I need to write this using list comprehension:

```
alter = map (\x -> if x == 0 then 1 else 0)
```

it gives e.g.

```
alter [1,1,0]  
> [0,0,1]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't write it point-free using list comprehension:

```
alter xs = [if x == 0 then 1 else 0 | x <- xs]
```